# tuple identity proof..

Tags: elementary-set-theory, alternative-proof, solution-verification

I have in one book little proof to create.

We know that tuple can be expressed as $(a,b) = \{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$

and I have too prove that:

$ a = c \  \land b = d \implies  (a,b) = (c,d) $

I know this proof is very trivial but I'm a little too unexperienced in proofs so i want to ask if this proof I created is valid enought?

$a=c\ \land b=d \implies a=c=x\ \land b=d=y \implies \{\{x\},\{x,y\}\} = \{\{a\}\{a,b\}\} = \{\{c\},\{c,d\}\} \implies (a,b) = (c,d) $

Or is there any more basic proof?

Comment: As it stands, your proof doesn't make any sense. To show $(a,b) = (c,d)$ you must show $\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\} = \{\{c\},\{c,d\}\}$ as set equality, i.e. all the elements in each are elements in the other.

Comment: but if  $ a = x $ then $ \{a\} =\{x\}  $ or can't I use this?

Comment: Sure, but more care is needed than that. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Kuratowski_definition for a proof of equality using this definition.

Comment: Note that the direction you want to prove is trivial, but it's the other direction that makes this definition of tuple useful: if $(a,b)=(c,d)$ then $a=c$ and $b=d$.

Comment: IMV a proof is not needed. $a$ and $c$ are labels/notations of the same set and $b$ and $d$ are labels/notations for the same set. Then automatically $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ are labels/notations for the same set. What you are doing can be compared with e.g. "proving" the implication $x=y\implies x+1=y+1$.